# Get distinct values in a table

Tags: sql

I have a small temp table with 2 columns: ErrorName and Value.

```
ErrorName|Value
---------|-----
Error1   |3
Error2   |2
Error3   |2
Error1   |1
Error2   |1
```

I want to sum up the value field based on the ErrorName and return something like this:

```
Error1   |4
Error2   |3
Error3   |2
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? [tag:sql] is the tag for the SQL language. Use [tag:sql-server] for the SQL Server database server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You will want sum of Value over ErrorName.

```
select ErrorName, sum(Value) as TotalValue from myTempTable group by ErrorName
```

Comment: This works and it was posted before Dustin's. Thanks both of you

Answer (score 1):

You are interested in grouping.  You should get what you want with the following

```
Select
  ErrorName,
  SUM(Value) As ErrorCount
From Table
Group By ErrorName
```